# Can an employee complete the I9 form remotely?

Tags: united-states, employment

[This](https://www.uscis.gov/completing-form-i-9-for-remote-hire) USCIS instruction says that:

> Employers may designate an authorized representative to fill out Forms I-9 on behalf of their company, including personnel officers, foremen, agents or notary public.

On the other hand, the Employment Eligibility Verification consists of [three sections](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central/complete-and-correct-form-i-9). In [Section 1](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central/complete-correct-form-i-9/completing-section-1-employee-information-and-attestation), can an employee complete the I9 form remotely?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced employers using web-based employee on-boarding processes where the employee fills out a form on a website like Zenefits or Gusto, instead of filling out the I-9 form. So yes, I think it is possible for the employee to complete Section 1 remotely.

However, the employer's representative must still physically examine the List A or List B and C documents in person for Section 2 (though [an exception](https://www.ice.gov/news/releases/ice-announces-another-extension-i-9-compliance-flexibility-no-more-extensions) allows employers to examine documents remotely until August 19, 2020).

Comment: What happens if they don't examine the document in person?  I don't think my employer did; I just sent them a scan.  Can they get in trouble if the employee is in fact authorized, or is it only a problem if the employee is unauthorized?

Comment: @phoog: I think they can get in trouble if they didn't examine it, as in section 2 of the I-9 they attest under penalty of perjury that they examined it. They can have you send them a scan, but they would still need to have someone come and examine the documents in person. That is before COVID-19; during COVID-19, the in-person examination requirement is on hold.